# GDAL scripts not working on QGIS and High Sierra

Tags: gdal, qgis-3, clip, installation, mac

I had the same issue that has already been posted with running GDAL scripts on MacOs with QGIS3. I am trying to clip a raster and used to get this error:

```
GDAL command output: /bin/sh: (scriptname).py: command not found
```

Then I followed the workaround from the readme.txt to use customs variable and now I have another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalAlgorithm.py", line 115, in processAlgorithm GdalUtils.runGdal(commands, feedback) 
File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalUtils.py", line 83, in runGdal if not path.lower() in envval.lower().split(os.pathsep): 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I also tried to re-install GDAL after QGIS3 but no luck.

I am running High Sierra 10.13.4 and QGIS3 3.0.2.
For info, it doesn't work on QGIS 2 either.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you read   [KyngChaos:QGIS 3 Tools & Processing Workaround](http://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2018/20180406_qgis_tools_processing_workaround) ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! I have and I have followed this step but it still doesn't work. The error message is just a different on. I get the long one I posted above...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by modifying in the preferences of QGIS, tab system, a PATH custom environment variable:

"Add to the end" | PATH | :/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs: /Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Programs: /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/UnixImageIO.framework/Programs

Answer (score 1):

I actually just solved it. It turned out that the 'Prepend" from the apply popup didn't save on the first try. Not it is, and it works!
The output raster (a tiff image) just looks very weird (different colours than the original not clipped raster)... I'll work on it.
Thanks for your help!